# linux find regex - can I use 'search', instead of match?

Tags: linux, regex, find

the `find` utility is powerful, but I'd need some additional features.

its `-regex` search treats each filename (or dirname) as a string and applys given regex only at the beginning of name. like python's `re.match(..)`. if it doesn't produce a match, it won't be found.

for example If i want to find files containing 'log', (I know there are simpler ways to find files whose filename contains 'log' without regex, but it's only for an example)

```
$ find -regex 'log'
(nothing)

$ find -regex '\./.*log.*$'
./log9
./log7
./log5
./log0
./log2
./log4
./log6
./log8
./log3
./log1
```

so, is there a way to make `find` with `-regex` that uses regex on filenames, like `grep` or  python's `re.search(..)` - not only at the start of a string, but anywhere where it can match?

Answer (score 0):

The regex is not only applied to the beginning, it is applied to the *whole* string. You just need to give the right regex, one that captures the entire file name:

```
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 0 Oct  6 15:46 aaafoo
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 0 Oct  6 15:46 aaafooaaa
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 0 Oct  6 15:46 fooaaa
$ find . -regex ".*foo.*"  
./aaafoo
./aaafooaaa
./fooaaa
$ find . -regex "^./foo.*"  
./fooaaa
$ find . -regex ".*foo"
./aaafoo
```

You might be looking for the `-name` test, which takes globs, not regular expressions:

```
$ find  . -name "*foo*" 
./aaafoo
./aaafooaaa
./fooaaa
```

Comment: thanks, but your example clearly indicates that all the regex is applied only to beginning(and that produces a match, because of `.*` or `^./` at the beginning of regexes, which would be unnecessary if the regexs are not only tried at the beginning of a string.) `-name` is only for globs.. so, guess the only solution is me writing more longer regexes.

Comment: @thkang what I'm saying is that the regex needs to describe the _entire_ string from the beginning to the end. It is not only matched against the beginning it's matched against the entire thing. There is no file name you cannot describe that way. Simply adding a `.*` allows you to match anywhere within the string. I can't think of any example of a file name that I could not write a regex for.